# Delegate textShouldBeginEditing is not called in subclass of NSTextView

Tags: cocoa

I'm writing an application on Mac OS X (Lion) which is a job management program. The data source is MySQL.

In one window I have several NSTextFields which are subclassed to my own subclass of NSTextField. My subclass has the name HDLTextField. Inside my subclass I have implemented the delegate textShouldBeginEditing which is working great.

Now I have a NSTextView in my window which is subclassed to my subclass HDLTextView with its superclass NSTextView. But the implemented delegate textShouldBeginEditing is not called, allthough NSTextView as a subclass to NSText supports this delegate.

So why does the delegate work with NSTextField but not with NSTextView?

```
@implementation HDLTextView

- (BOOL)textShouldBeginEditing:(NSText *)textObject
{
    DLog(@"huu");
    if ([[[self window] windowController] recordShouldEdit]) {
    [[[self window] windowController] sendDocumentEdited];
    return YES;
}
    return NO;
}

- (void) setItDisabled: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self setEditable:NO];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor controlColor]];
}

- (void) setItEnabled: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self setEditable:YES];
    [self setBackgroundColor:[NSColor controlBackgroundColor]];
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) awakeFromNib
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(setItDisabled:) 
                                             name:@"HDLRecordLockedByOtherUser"
                                           object:[[self window] windowController]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(setItEnabled:) 
                                             name:@"HDLRecordReleased"
                                           object:[[self window] windowController]];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"HDLRecordLockedByOtherUser" object:[[self window] windowController]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"HDLRecordReleased" object:[[self window] windowController]];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

BTW - while I'm writing this application as a newbie, stackoverflow gave me all the answers I was looking for. So, thank you very much everybody.

Comment: Did you start with Apple's [Subclassing NSTextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/Subclassing.html) document? You may not really need to be creating a subclass.

Comment: Is your text view its own delegate?!

Comment: SSteve, yes I read the Subclassing NSTextView document. But it didn't help. And I know, that I don't need create a subclass. But as I have lots of NSTextViews in my windows, it makes things fairly easy. And, why does subclassing with the delegate textShouldBeginEditing works for NSTextField but not for NSTextView?

Comment: noa, what do you mean with "Is your text view its own delegate"? As the NSTextView in InterfaceBuilder is a subclass of my HDLTextView, it should call the delegate in his own class, as it does in HDLTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides this [overview of delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

According to the [NSTextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/textShouldBeginEditing%3a) documentation, its `textShouldBeginEditing:` method requests permission to begin editing a text object. This is *not* a delegate method – it's a method of NSTextField which subclasses can implement.

To use delegation, you would instead create a different object which implements the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol, implement the [control:textShouldBeginEditing:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextField/textShouldBeginEditing%3a) method, and set it as the text field's delegate. You can do this by connecting an outlet or by calling `setDelegate` on the text field.

NSTextView does not have a `textShouldBeginEditing:` method.

So, try connecting your NSTextView's delegate outlet to itself.

Or, use the delegation pattern as it's intended:

1. Rename your class to HDLTextViewController, subclass NSObject, and implement the `NSTextViewDelegate` protocol.

   ```
   @interface HDLTextViewController : NSObject <NSTextViewDelegate>
   ```
2. In that class, implement the parent protocol's [textShouldBeginEditing:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSTextDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextDelegate/textShouldBeginEditing%3a) method.
3. In the nib, insert an NSObject and set the custom class to HDLTextViewController.
4. Replace your HDLTextView with a standard NSTextView and connect its delegate outlet to your new controller object.